# XML parsing exception org.xml.sax.SAXParseException cvc-elt.1

Tags: java, xml, sax, saxparser, bonita

My XML contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<organization:Organization xmlns:organization="http://www.bonitasoft.org/ns/organization/6.0.0-beta-016">
......
</organization:Organization>
```

For complete XML file, Please have a look at :
https://github.com/bonitasoft/bonita-examples/blob/master/rest-api-example/src/main/resources/ACME.xml

I get this error on server side (JAVA & Tomcat) :

**org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 106; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'organization:Organization'.**
(Full stack trace is below)

I changed the 'organization' tag to just `<organization> ... </organization>`

Still I get same error:
 **cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'organization'**

### ***EDIT***

---

It works when I change the xmlns URI as

```
<organization:Organization xmlns:organization="http://documentation.bonitasoft.com/organization-xml-schema/1.1">
```

Can someone please explain.

---

I am trying to run the REST API example mentioned in the Bonitasoft documentation : http://documentation.bonitasoft.com/create-your-first-project-web-rest-api-and-maven-0
(I guess it is pure XML parsing problem & it has nothing to do with Bonitasoft code)

Can some one help me to resolve this.

Thank you very much for your time.

**FULL STACK TRACE :**

```
2015-08-25 16:37:19.885 +0900 org.bonitasoft.web.toolkit.server.servlet.ToolkitHttpServlet org.bonitasoft.web.toolkit.server.servlet.ToolkitHttpServlet catchAllExceptions 
SEVERE: Can't import organization. Please check that your file is well-formed
org.bonitasoft.web.toolkit.server.ServiceException: Can't import organization. Please check that your file is well-formed
    at org.bonitasoft.console.server.service.OrganizationImportService.run(OrganizationImportService.java:62)
    at org.bonitasoft.web.toolkit.server.ServiceServletCall.run(ServiceServletCall.java:92)
    at org.bonitasoft.web.toolkit.server.ServiceServletCall.doPost(ServiceServletCall.java:72)
    at org.bonitasoft.web.toolkit.server.servlet.ToolkitHttpServlet.doPost(ToolkitHttpServlet.java:188)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at org.bonitasoft.web.toolkit.server.servlet.ToolkitHttpServlet.service(ToolkitHttpServlet.java:75)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.bonitasoft.web.toolkit.server.servlet.ToolkitHttpServlet.service(ToolkitHttpServlet.java:226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.bonitasoft.console.common.server.login.filter.AuthenticationFilter.isAuthorized(AuthenticationFilter.java:152)
    at org.bonitasoft.console.common.server.login.filter.AuthenticationFilter.doAuthenticationFiltering(AuthenticationFilter.java:134)
    at org.bonitasoft.console.common.server.login.filter.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.bonitasoft.console.security.SessionFixationValve.invoke(SessionFixationValve.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.bonitasoft.engine.identity.OrganizationImportException: USERNAME=install | org.bonitasoft.engine.xml.SValidationException:

**org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 106; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'organization:Organization'.**
    at org.bonitasoft.engine.api.impl.IdentityAPIImpl.importOrganization(IdentityAPIImpl.java:1427)
    at org.bonitasoft.engine.api.impl.IdentityAPIImpl.importOrganization(IdentityAPIImpl.java:1414)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor58.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.bonitasoft.engine.api.impl.ServerAPIImpl.invokeAPI(ServerAPIImpl.java:467)
    at org.bonitasoft.engine.api.impl.ServerAPIImpl$2.call(ServerAPIImpl.java:436)
    at org.bonitasoft.engine.transaction.JTATransactionServiceImpl.executeInTransaction(JTATransactionServiceImpl.java:312)
    at org.bonitasoft.engine.api.impl.ServerAPIImpl.invokeAPIInTransaction(ServerAPIImpl.java:443)
    at org.bonitasoft.engine.api.impl.ServerAPIImpl.invokeAPI(ServerAPIImpl.java:278)
    at org.bonitasoft.engine.api.impl.ServerAPIImpl.invokeMethod(ServerAPIImpl.java:131)
    at org.bonitasoft.engine.api.impl.ClientInterceptor.invoke(ClientInterceptor.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.importOrganization(Unknown Source)
    at org.bonitasoft.console.server.service.OrganizationImportService.run(OrganizationImportService.java:60)
    ... 38 more

**Caused by: org.bonitasoft.engine.xml.SValidationException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 106; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'organization:Organization'.**
    at org.bonitasoft.engine.xml.SAXValidator.validate(SAXValidator.java:91)
    at org.bonitasoft.engine.xml.SAXValidator.validate(SAXValidator.java:80)
    at org.bonitasoft.engine.xml.parse.SAXParser.validate(SAXParser.java:138)
    at org.bonitasoft.engine.identity.xml.ImportOrganization.execute(ImportOrganization.java:131)
    at org.bonitasoft.engine.api.impl.IdentityAPIImpl.importOrganization(IdentityAPIImpl.java:1425)
    ... 51 more

**Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 106; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'organization:Organization'.**
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1906)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:746)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:379)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3138)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:880)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.StreamValidatorHelper.validate(StreamValidatorHelper.java:155)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:116)
    at javax.xml.validation.Validator.validate(Validator.java:124)
    at org.bonitasoft.engine.xml.SAXValidator.validate(SAXValidator.java:89)
    ... 55 more
```

Comment: Please don't point to files on other sites, which may well have changed when people come to read this question in 6 months time. If the questions aren't persistent, people are less likely to answer them, because none of us like having archived answers on the site that no longer make any sense.

Comment: @Michael Kay : Thanks for the suggestion. I tried to pate the contents of XML file along with question. But I get an error "Number of characters exceeded". Please let me know if there is any better way. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `Cannot find the declaration of element 'organization:Organization` shows that you are trying to validate the XML instance against some schema. That schema will contain definitions of a number of elements in some namespace. The fact that it works with namespace `http://documentation.bonitasoft.com/organization-xml-schema/1.1` suggests that this is the correct namespace required by the schema. If that is the case, then using a different namespace of your own invention will cause the error you observed. it's purely a question of whether you are using the namespace defined in your schema.

Comment: @Michael Kay Thank you very much for the explanation and yes, I could understand same from sgpalit's comment.